# Parsing travel duration data

Tags: parsing, ios, swift

I'm trying to parse an estimated travel duration and distance between two waypoints using Google Directions API. Tap on [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=walking&origin=30.2089607,-97.6682898&destination=30.2089607,-97.6762898&sensor=false) to see an example of data received.

```
private class func parseTravelData(
    data: AnyObject!,
    mode: ESTMode,
    completion: (NSDictionary?) -> Void) {
        var receivedData = data as? NSDictionary

        if let routes = receivedData?["routes"] as? NSArray {
            if routes.count > 0 {
                if let legs = routes[0]["legs"] as? NSArray {
                    if legs.count > 0 {

                        var dur: String? = nil

                        if let duration = legs[0]["duration"] as? NSDictionary {
                            if let v = duration["value"] as? Float {
                                if v > ConnectionManager().timeMax && mode == .Walking {
                                    completion(nil) // resend using drive mode
                                }
                                else {
                                    if let t = duration["text"] as? String {
                                        dur = t
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if let d = dur {
                            if let distance = legs[0]["distance"] as? NSDictionary {
                                if let dist = distance["text"] as? String {
                                    completion([
                                        "duration": d,
                                        "distance": dist])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This code works fine but looks awful. What I need is do nothing if data is incorrect. I can't come anything up with it. The main goal is avoiding of getting different unwrapping errors if something is wrong. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this code is correct or will compile but here is my attempt...

```
private class func parseTravelData(data: AnyObject!, mode: ESTMode, completion: NSDictionary? -> Void) {
    let receivedData = data as? NSDictionary
    let routes = receivedData?["routes"] as? NSArray
    let legs = routes?.firstObject?["legs"] as? NSDictionary

    if let firstLeg = legs?.firstObject as? NSDictionary {
        let firstLegDurationDict = firstLeg["duration"] as? NSDictionary
        let firstLegDuration = firstLegDurationDict?["value"] as? Float

        if firstLegDuration > ConnectionManager().timeMax && mode == .Walking {
            completion(nil) // resend using drive mode
        } else if let durationStr = firstLegDurationDict?["text"] as? String {
            let distanceDict = firstLeg["distance"] as? NSDictionary
            if let distanceStr = distanceDict?["text"] as? String {
                completion(["duration": durationStr, "distance": distanceStr])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few things I did to try to make the code more concise

I noticed that the interesting stuff only happens if the route contains a leg. So I was able to eliminate a few if statement blocks by using optional chaining and moving code out of the if conditions and into the `receivedData`, `routes`, and `legs` variables. (The individual variables are not strictly necessary but make the code more readable). So the first "if let" check happens to see if there is actually a leg in the optional `legs` array.

Another optimization I made is that I moved the `if let d = dur` block into the else statement above since the code will only proceed if `duration["text"]` exists. This also allowed me to eliminate the `var dur: String? = nil` statement as well.

I also renamed some variables for more clarity, for example I renamed `v` to `firstLegDuration`.

I was able to eliminate the `if let v` block since if `v` (which is now `firstLegDuration`) is nil then `v > ConnectionManager().timeMax` will be false since `nil > AnyObject == false`.

One thing I noticed that the `completion` does not get called in all cases, which to me seems weird, so if there is an error or missing data then nothing will happen.